# Nightmarejs external popup

Tags: nightmare

I am trying to login to a webpage through Facebook with Nightmarejs. When I click "Login" button a facebook popup pops where I should enter my credentials.
Is it possible to interact with this popup using Nightmarejs?
Thank you.